# apply functon to column by condition on another column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table "temp"

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr) 

temp <- data.table(name=c("test1","test2","test3","test4"), 
                   country=c("usa","usa","mexico","mexico"))
```

I want to apply function to column "name" where country is "usa" in data.table way.

For example apply function `str_replace()` from `stringr`:

```
str_replace( temp[country == "usa"]$name ,'\\w*[a-z]', '')
```

any advice or links are welcome!

Comment: Please take your time to read [these](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started). Also, prior posting questions on the R tag, please consult the examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). If this wasn't for akrun, we would probably close this question as not reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
setDT(temp)[country=="usa", name := str_replace(name, "\\w*[a-z]", "")]
```